# Windows - find a process that opens the cmd promp every hour

Tags: windows, cmd, process

I have a process that runs aprox. every hour which opens the cmd promp for a split second. It is pretty annoying especially in games because it puts the game into the taskbar. There is any way to find what is the process and to prevent it from happening? Also I don't know if it's malicious or not.

OS - windows 10

Comment: Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) could probably identify the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely seems like a malicious software.

Since finding a single process is very difficult, the easiest approach is to download [malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/)
which is free and scan your whole computer.

You can also try Windows Defender if you don't want to download anything else, just make sure it is up to date.

If the scan doesn't help just get help from [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us),
because we can't help you much from here and the support technicians can get directly into your OS.